# What is the correct form of terragrunt terraform source to get module from private gitlab terraform registry

Tags: gitlab, terraform, devops, terragrunt

Could you kindly help me with my issue?

I have terraform module on private gitlab instance and I can obtain it with http-source from terragrunt like this:

```
terraform {
  source = "https://gitlab.mysite.com/gitlab_group_name/gitlab_subgroup_name/project_name"
  extra_arguments "init_args" {
    commands = [
      "init"
    ]
    arguments = [
    ]
  }
}
```

Then I've pushed this module to gitlab terraform registry with version number 0.0.1 and tried huge amount of variants of terragrunt source like

```
source = "tfr://gitlab.mysite.com/gitlab_group_name/gitlab_subgroup_name/project_name?version=0.0.1"
```

Terragrunt somehow rewrites URL above to something like

```
https://gitlab.mysite.com/api/v4/packages/terraform/modules/v1/gitlab_group_name/gitlab_subgroup_name/project_name/0.0.1/download
```

and throw expected error

```
error receiving HTTP data
```

Is there any way to get module from private gitlab terraform registry with terragrunt using tfr protocol?

Comment: as you mentioned it's a private repository could you please try setting up this environment variable `TG_TF_REGISTRY_TOKEN`  with the correct token value and then try.  Documentation at [here](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/reference/config-blocks-and-attributes/#terraform)

Comment: Thanks for help! I didn't mention that terragrunt creates `.terraformrc` with credentials (access token) in the target folder, so, I don't think that it is a creds problem.